# How to write this kind of sentence for a distinguished lecture series?

Tags: esl

I work in a Chinese university and recently our department has decided to start a Distinguished Lecture Series in Physics. We want to give the invited speaker some kind of document showing that, basically, he has been a speaker at this series. I'm not sure what's the best way to write this sentence. I'm not even sure what this kind of document should be called. A certificate? Some kind of award? Please give me some clue. Thank you very much.

Comment: "Certificate of Appreciation" is a good catch-all choice, if given when the speaker presents or afterwards.  "Certificate of Acknowledgement" would work before or after.

Comment: This seems like a weird thing to give a certificate for.  Presumably the speaker can just download the announcement for the talk if proof of having been a speaker is needed.  Or perhaps sending a thank you letter afterward would work?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, on what to call this document, I would suggest "Bonafide Certificate of Acknowledgement" or simply "Certificate of Acknowledgement" as that's what it is exactly, as opposed to being an award of any kind.

Secondly, on what to write in the document, I would suggest something on the lines of the following:

"This is to certify the participation (or) contribution of ____Mr/Ms. XXXXXX____ as ____Subject Matter Expert / Distinguished Speaker____ in Distinguished Lecture Series in Physics held at ____XXXXXX University____ on DD-MMM-YYYY. [[Optional note of thanks]] [[Authorized Signatory]] "

Comment: I would not use "bona fide" (two words, BTW) on a certificate like that.

Comment: @HotLicks: Agreed. Bona fide would be ideal to certify the reality/authenticity of something as the purpose.

Comment: It's best to print it on the thickest paper available, and to put a decorative but dignified BORDER (e.g., scrollwork) around the certificate. Make it about half-page size (about 5x8") and orient it landscape (i.e., long edges are top & bottom).

Comment: Thank you very much for all your kind help! Cannot vote up because it requires 15 reputations. Sorry.

Comment: @Bill As the OP you can tick the answer as correct though (if you wish) and that's worth more than all the up-votes in the world.